Rigify's 'Generate Rig' button is disabled
You can download it.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_SLF-Pa0Efnt8s-5Ey1aCU5u1Vi25Fmv/view?usp=drive_link
There is a problem with the 'generate rig'
Attached is the file.
There are two models.
For one, you can click the generate rig button.
But that's impossible for the other one.
How can I change it to make it possible?
Please give us answers from experts.
Thanks!

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

For the one called metarig, the Rig Type of its bones are set which allows Rigify to generate the rig.

For the one called Body, this is not the case, so Rigify is unable to generate a rig for it.

You need to set the Rig type for the relevant bones. To do so, you'll find that you need to create at least one Bone Collection under Bone Collection UI and assign its button to a UI Layout. You should be able to generate the rig at that point, but the generated rig will not match the Body rig, because you have unapplied transforms.
Using Rigify is quite involved. Maybe reading the manual or following a tutorial is the best way to start.

Thank you very much. You've been a great help.

You're welcome! If this answer addressed your question, please accept it to help others who may run into the same issue.
